# VBA code to Sum using subtotal for different columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am having the code in VBA that will sum the entire column that i filtered and that sum count is copying  it in another sheet for calculation. I have different columns each time am writing the code separate.

Can some one help me out write in a single line so that i can reduce the lines of code.

Please find the code.

```
worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B10") = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(9, Range("AP2:AP" & Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C10") = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(9, Range("BT2:BT" & Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D10") = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(9, Range("CZ2:CZ" & Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E10") = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(9, Range("EE2:EE" & Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F10") = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(9, Range("FK2:FK" & Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G10") = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(9, Range("GP2:GP" & Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H10") = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(9, Range("HV2:HV" & Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
worksheets("Sheet2").Range("I10") = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(9, Range("JB2:JB" & Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
worksheets("Sheet2").Range("J10") = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(9, Range("KG2:KG" & Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K10") = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(9, Range("LM2:LM" & Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
worksheets("Sheet2").Range("L10") = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(9, Range("MR2:MR" & Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
worksheets("Sheet2").Range("M10") = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(9, Range("NX2:NX" & Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))
```

Comment: Actually I see no rule/pattern in that and no way to reduce the amount of code. Every line does something different, every line uses different ranges, and I see no pattern/rule to create the address names on the fly.

Comment: The only way I can see is to use a `With WorkSheets("Sheet2")` and set a variable to `Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` and use that instead. That would clean it up a bit, but you would still need all those lines as @Pᴇʜ said.

Comment: Also if your code is working (no errors no issues) and you are just looking for someone to review it, that is off-topic here and should be posted at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If your range to keep the calculated data is clearly situated on row 10, consecutive columns, can you find a different way to determine ranges type "KG2:KG ..."? It is obvious that starting from second row, they may have headers. **Do that headers are all the time the same**? In such a case, the code can be optimized, I think... Since all cells keeping the result are from "Sheet2", a logic assumption would state that subtotals are done in the active shape. Is that correct?

Comment: At least, do you all the time use those columns letter? I mean, is it  possible an inserted column to appear between the existing ones and you would need to change your code? In such a case, iterating between the column headers would also save you from code adaptation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt to parametrize the code, so that you can enter columns and output range and eventually turn it into a function if needed. Note, if number of output cells differ than number of columns totalled, an error will be produced. Should be wiser to check if these arrays differ and stop the code with a warning.

Issue found: Using Debug.Print() and a section of the original formula related to finding last row I found it returns **1** for all columns. After the change the original formula would look like:

```
Sub populateTotals()
        Dim sht As Worksheet: Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet2")
        Dim mycols As String: mycols = "G,H,I,J"
        Set Rng = sht.Range("B10:E10")

        SplitCatcher = Split(mycols, ",")

        Dim i As Integer: i = 0

        For Each Cell In Rng
            Cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(9, Range(SplitCatcher(i) & "2:" & SplitCatcher(i) & Cells(sht.Rows.Count, SplitCatcher(i)).End(xlUp).Row))
            i = i + 1
        Next Cell

End Sub
```

I tested it with a subtotal function and filtered out one row. It returns correct results.

[image]

Comment: While using Sum the count is getting calculated wrongly. I tried with Subtotal in the place of sum but throwing the error. Can you please giv me the code for subtotal.@Jacek Kotowski

Comment: @SekarNaidu See the ammended answer.

Comment: its working intermittently , Now every thing giving count as 0. Not sure nothing changes made on it.

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing on the data side... if you could generate an excel file with bogus, random data, and paste it somewhere I may see the problem. However my answer seem to be valid, you can replace repetitions by creating lists of repetitive parts and iterate through non repeating line glueing together the string in each iteration.